# do you still need to stage a deleted file?

Tags: git

for example I already have delete this on my local and no longer needed in production should I stage it to update ? or shall I just leave it ?

[image]

Comment: And also commit it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you need to stage it before comitting.

Changes that you didn't stage don't exist for git. So if you want git to store that deletion then you need to stage it.

If you don't stage (and commit) then the commit you push will not represent your local changes fully: everyone who updates to that commit will get your changes, but the files you "deleted" will still be around for them.

Answer (score 0):

If a tree falls in the forest and no one is there to hear it, does it make a sound?

It's the same for your file. Git is about *commits*. If you make a change locally and you don't commit, then as far as Git is concerned, *nothing happened*. Is that what you want? Do you want this file to continue to be present in all commits, both those by you and both by others, for the rest of time?

If so, do nothing. But then it is hard to see why you deleted the file in the first place.

But if not, then you need to make a *commit* that lacks this file.

Note that exactly how you proceed depends on how you deleted the file. Did you just throw it away behind Git's back? Then you will need to *add* the file (to stage it) before you commit. The correct way, however, was to say `git rm`, because that removes the file both from the working tree and from the index (stage), and then your next commit just includes that fact.